# How do you plead

Tags: phrase-meaning

At the courtroom

Judge: Silence in court now. **How do you plead**? Guilty or not guilty?

Man: I plead not guilty.

Judge: Accused pleaded not guilty. Now, that still has to be proved. Let's examine the evidence.

---

What does "**How do you plead**" mean?

Comment: If you google **how do you plead?** you will find numerous sites that answer your question..

Comment: Please find a better source to learn English.  This dialogue is very unnatural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the English legal system and others based upon it, the defendant is asked to specify whether they are "guilty" or "not guilty" of what they are accused of.  The judge asks them how they plead.  Their response (or plea) is either "guilty" or "not guilty".

> **plead** *Law no object, with complement* State formally in court whether one is guilty or not guilty of the offence with which one is charged. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plead))

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with:

> Now, that still has to be proved.

You might want to say:

Now, let the case proceed.

To answer your question:

It means:  Do you say to the court that you are guilty or that you are not guilty?

Comment: The OP is quoting an 1980s Canadian local TV ESL show (or parody of an ESL show)  It has lots of examples of completely unnatural English, apparently to illustrate a particular point of vocabulary or grammar.  Here the writers are probably trying to illustrate the meaning of "prove".  But of course no Judge would ever speak like that in real life.  It is a truly weird show, and a terrible sourse to learn English from.